# Gevent monkeypatching breaking multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gevent

I am attempting to use multiprocessing's pool to run a group of processes, each of which will run a gevent pool of greenlets. The reason for this is that there is a lot of network activity, but also a lot of CPU activity, so to maximise my bandwidth and all of my CPU cores, I need multiple processes AND gevent's async monkey patching. I am using multiprocessing's manager to create a queue which the processes will access to get data to process.

Here is a simplified fragment of the code:

```
import multiprocessing

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(thread=False)

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
q = manager.Queue()
```

Here is the exception it produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multimonkeytest.py", line 7, in <module>
    q = manager.Queue()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 667, in temp
    token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 565, in _create
    conn = self._Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 175, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 409, in answer_challenge
    message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
 IOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I believe this must be due to some difference between the behaviour of the normal socket module and gevent's socket module.

If I monkeypatch within the subprocess, The queue is created successfully, but when the subprocess tries to get() from the queue, a very similar exception occurs. The socket does need to be monkeypatched due to doing large numbers of network requests in the subprocesses.

My version of gevent, which I believe is the latest:

```
>>> gevent.version_info
(1, 0, 0, 'alpha', 3)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: related: http://bugs.python.org/issue6056

Answer (score 21):

use `monkey.patch_all(thread=False, socket=False)`

I have run into the same issue in a similar situation and tracked this down to line 115 in `gevent/monkey.py` under the `patch_socket()` function: `_socket.socket = socket.socket`. Commenting this line out prevents the breakage.

This is where gevent replaces the stdlib `socket` library with its own. `multiprocessing.connection` uses the `socket` library quite extensively, and is apparently not tolerant to this change.

Specifically, you will see this in any scenario where a module you import performs a `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` call without setting `socket=False`. In my case it was `grequests` that did this, and I had to override the patching of the socket module to fix this error.

Comment: Can I use requests library with gevent without the patching the socket?

Answer (score 11):

Application of multiprocessing in the context of gevent is unfortunately known to raise problems. Your rationale, however, is reasonable ("a lot of network activity, but also a lot of CPU activity"). If you like, have a look at http://gehrcke.de/gipc. This is designed primarily for your use case. With gipc, you can easily spawn a few fully gevent-aware child processes and let them cooperatively talk to each other and/or with the parent through pipes.

If you have specific questions, you're welcome to get back to me.

Comment: I personally think it's the thoughtless monkey patching that's problematic. Anything that uses gevent should come with a very large warning sign about what it's going to break. The average programmer who hasn't yet encountered this particular quirk of gevent-multiprocessing incompatibility would (rightfully) assume that gevent doesn't break stdlib features. It's not exactly obvious that gevent doesn't patch the IPC functions (which is doable) when it patches socket.

Comment: I tried the gipc approach. Since it misses the Queue object, alternative implementation using pipes was too convoluted. See `nose-gevented-multiprocess` module instead

Answer (score 3):

If you will use original Queue, then you code will work normally even with monkey patched socket.

```
import multiprocessing

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(thread=False)

q= multiprocessing.Queue()
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrote a replacement Nose Multiprocess plugin - this one should play well with all kinds of crazy Gevent-based patching.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-gevented-multiprocess/

https://github.com/dvdotsenko/nose_gevent_multiprocess

- Switches from `multiprocess.fork` to plain `subprocess.popen` for worker processes (fixes module-level erroneously shared objects issues for me)
- Switched from multiprocess.Queue to JSON-RPC over HTTP for master-to-clients RPC
- This can now theoretically allow tests to be distributed to multiple machines

Answer (score 1):

Your provided code works for me on Windows 7.

**EDIT:**

Removed previous answer, because I've tried your code on Ubuntu 11.10 VPS, and  I'm getting the same error.

Look's like [Eventlet have this issue too](https://bitbucket.org/which_linden/eventlet/issue/108/monkey_patch-breaks-multiprocessingmanager)

Comment: The error is occurring without actually doing any requests, but I have also tested with a local gevent bottle.py powered server.

I am getting the traceback on both OS X Lion and Ubuntu 11.04 VPS, both with Python 2.7. What OS / Python / Gevent are you using?

Comment: @user964375, Hm, on Ubuntu 11.10 (VPS) i'm getting the same error. No errors on Win7.

Comment: Tested on windows xp, and the code, even without the gevent part breaks after some time. Seems to be an issue in multiprocessing module.