# CherryPy, Multiprocessing and Gevent monkey patching

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cherrypy, gevent, monkeypatching

I'm attempting to use a combination of cherrypy + multiprocessing (to launch worker 'processes') + gevent (to launch parallel i/o greenlets from within the worker 'processes'). It seems the easiest way of doing this is to monkeypatch multiprocessing, as greenlets can only operate in the main application process.

However, it looks like the monkey patching works for some parts of multiprocessing and not others. Here is my sample CherryPy server:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import gevent
import cherrypy
import multiprocessing

def launch_testfuncs():
    jobs = [gevent.spawn(testfunc)
            for i in range(0, 12)]

    gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=10)

def testfunc():
    print 'testing'

class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        launch_testfuncs()

        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

    def index_proc(self):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=launch_testfuncs)
        proc.start()
        proc.join()

        return "Hello World 2!"
    index_proc.exposed = True

    def index_pool(self):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
        return "Hello World 3!"
    index_pool.exposed = True

    def index_namespace(self):
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        anamespace = manager.Namespace()
        anamespace.val = 23
        return "Hello World 4!"
    index_namespace.exposed = True


cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

The following works after monkey patching:

- `index` - just spawning greenlets from within the cherrypy class directly
- `index_proc` - use `multiprocessing.Process` to launch a new process, then spawn the greenlets from that process

The following have issues:

- `index_pool` - launch a `multiprocessing.Pool` - **hangs and never returns**
- `index_namespace` - initialize a `multiprocessing.Manager` namespace to manage shared memory within a pool/collection of workers - **returns following error message:**

  ```
  [15/Nov/2012:17:19:31] HTTP Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
  response.body = self.handler()
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
  self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 34, in __call__
  return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    File "server.py", line 39, in index_namespace
  anamespace = manager.Namespace()
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 667, in temp
  token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 565, in _create
  conn = self._Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 175, in Client
  answer_challenge(c, authkey)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 414, in answer_challenge
  response = connection.recv_bytes(256)        # reject large message
  IOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
  ```

I tried finding some documentation relating to this in the gevent docs, but couldn't find anything that deals with this. Is it just that gevent's monkey patching is incomplete? Has anyone else had similar issues and is there a way around it?

Comment: I've also removed the CherryPy wrapper, and tried calling index_pool() and index_namespace() directly with the same result – i.e. the interpreter hangs for the former, and returns the 'Resource temporarily unavailable' error message in the latter case.

Comment: The following seems to also discuss the breakage of multiprocessing.Manager(), unfortunately without a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678307/gevent-monkeypatching-breaking-multiprocessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a result of `gevent.socket` being non-blocking, meaning that any `socket.recv_bytes(X)` call will throw that error if `X` bytes are not immediately available on the socket. Specifically, the `gevent.socket` is designed to not block the socket, ever.

The problem with `multiprocessing` arises because it uses the stdlib `socket` module and expects it to be blocking, while after you've `monkey.patch_all()`'d, the `socket` module has been replaced, and `multiprocessing.connection` is not designed to deal with the new asynchronous behaviour.

You can tell `monkey` not to patch the `socket`, but it means that anything that was leveraging asynchronous sockets in your application may incur some loss of performance due to this.

To do this call `patch_all` with `socket=False`: `patch_all(socket=False)`.

This is not an ideal solution, as you pretty much lose much of the benefit you would have gained from using `gevent` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same issue like yours. My solution was that I have just used the multiprocessing.Process() to spawn the fixed number processes. and finally join all, wait for completed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import gevent
import multiprocessing as mp


NUM = 10


def work(i):
    jobs = [gevent.spawn(func, i)
            for i in range(0, 12)]
    gevent.joinall(jobs)
    print "{} Done {}".format(mp.current_process().name, i)


def func(x):
    print "Gevent: {}".format(x)

def main():

    processes = [mp.Process(name="Process-{}".format(i), target=work, args=(i,)) for i in xrange(NUM)]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

output

```
Gevent: 0
Gevent: 1
Gevent: 2
Gevent: 3
Gevent: 4
Gevent: 5
Gevent: 6
Gevent: 7
Gevent: 8
Gevent: 9
Gevent: 10
Gevent: 11
Process-0 Done 11
Gevent: 0
Gevent: 1
Gevent: 2
Gevent: 3
Gevent: 4
Gevent: 5
Gevent: 6
Gevent: 7
Gevent: 8
Gevent: 9
Gevent: 10
Gevent: 11
Process-1 Done 11
Gevent: 0
Gevent: 1
Gevent: 2
Gevent: 3
Gevent: 4
Gevent: 5
Gevent: 6
Gevent: 7
Gevent: 8
Gevent: 9
Gevent: 10
Gevent: 11
Process-2 Done 11
Gevent: 0
... ...
```

So that is a solution for gevent working with multiprocessing.