# Celery tasks not works with gevent

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, gevent

When i use `celery` + `gevent` for tasks that uses `subprocess` module i'm getting following stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/venv/admin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 228, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/venv/admin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 415, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/webapp/admin/webadmin/apps/loggingquarantine/tasks.py", line 107, in release_mail_task
    res = call_external_script(popen_obj.communicate)
  File "/home/webapp/admin/webadmin/apps/core/helpers.py", line 42, in call_external_script
    return func_to_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 740, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1257, in _communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1287, in _communicate_with_poll
    poller = select.poll()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

My `manage.py` looks following (doing monkeypatch there):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gevent import monkey
import sys
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not 'celery' in sys.argv:
        monkey.patch_all()
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webadmin.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    sys.path.append(".")
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Is there a reason why celery tasks act like it wasn't patched properly?

p.s. strange thing that my local setup on Macos works fine while i getting such exceptions under Centos (all package versions are the same, init and config scripts too)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8678307/512251

Comment: What script do you use to launch your workers?

Comment: @btoueg

[celeryd](https://gist.github.com/Novarg/7199719#file-celeryd)
 and 
[sysconf/celeryd](https://gist.github.com/Novarg/7199701#file-celeryd-sysconf)

Comment: Is it normal that your shebang does not point to your venv?

Comment: I think this shouldn't be a problem because we activate venv via `source` command in celeryd script before actually call `manage.py`

Comment: use this: monkey.patch_all(subprocess=True)

Answer (score -1):

There's no simulation for poll in gevent so `monkey.patch_all` removes polling mechanisms that gevent.select does not simulate: poll, epoll, kqueue, kevent. See [gevent.monkey – Make the standard library cooperative](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#module-gevent.monkey).

Comment: Yes but `subprocess` module actually checks when `poll` available in `select` module or not. If it tries to use `_communicate_with_poll` then on the moment when `subprocess` was imported `select` wasn't patched, but how can it be if celery start via manage.py where i do patching.