# Using Gevent in a Multiprocessing Worker

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gevent, coroutine

Is it possible to use gevent in a multiprocessing worker? It seems to interrupt communication when it monkey-patches the socket-layer.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gipc/0.4.0

Comment: also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678307/gevent-monkeypatching-breaking-multiprocessing

Comment: The problem is not that I'm unaware of gipc. The problem is that I am using gipc, and it's disrupting my multiprocessing pipes from the worker side. The guy's post essentially says that he's having the same problem, and I'd be wary of exempting sockets for my use case.

Comment: You need to be more precise in your question. Generally, it is not recommended to set up a gevent architecture *before* forking. You duplicate the entire architecture, which is usually not what you want. gipc's approach then is to destroy the entire duplicate, which might indeed also not be what you want. You can neither blame gevent, nor gipc, you have to re-design your architecture.

Comment: There's also this comment in the documentation: "gipc automatically closes handles in the parent if provided to the child, and also closes those in the child that were not explicitly transferred to it. This auto-close behavior might be a limitation in certain special cases. However, it automatically prevents file descriptor leakage and forces developers to make deliberate choices about which handles should be transferred explicitly." If you are opening a file descriptor/socket in the parent then you can keep gipc from closing it by explicitly passing it to the client process.