# gevent affects multiprocessing in python3

Tags: python, python-requests, gevent, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing and gevent together in one program, here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests
#import gevent.monkey
#gevent.monkey.patch_all()

def download(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    return req.status_code, req.text[:22]

urls = ['http://www.ustchacker.com'] * 10
p = multiprocessing.Pool(20)
data = p.map(download, urls)
for status, text in data:
    print(status, text)

#a function using gevent, the function will 
#also use 'download' function
......
```

I comment out the second and the third rows. If I cancel the comments, the program will never run well. Why gevent affects multiprocessing? How to solve the problem so that I can use both multiprocessing and gevent in one program file?

Comment: What do you mean by "the second and third rows". Do you mean the monkey patching calls? If so, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678307/gevent-monkeypatching-breaking-multiprocessing). Also note that in general `gevent` and `multiprocessing` are tricky to use properly together, even without `multiprocessing`. The [`gipc`](http://gehrcke.de/gipc/) module can help with that, but I don't think it has support for `Pool`.

Comment: @dano    yep, thanks for the link of the similar question, but if I use `use monkey.patch_all(thread=False, socket=False, select=False)`, the performance of the gevent will decrease. What I want is to use both **gevent** and **multiprocessing** with high performance. How to make it?